# How to assign a matrix to the diagonals of another matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array, diagonal

I have a matrix  `D = zeros (30, 432);` i want to assign `d = [ 1 1 0 0; 0 0 1 1; 0 0 0 0];`
 to the diagonals of matrix D. i have the code below but it doesn't allow me to assign d for every diagonal values in D.

```
[N,~,P,Q]=size(D);
diagIndex=repmat(logical(eye(N)),[1 1 P Q]);
D(diagIndex)=d;
```

The output for 30x432 matrix would be like :

```
d 0 0 0
0 d 0 0
0 0 d 0
0 0 0 d
```

Comment: What exactly is the output that you want? Please provide that output. Please create a small sample example

Comment: Are you just looking for the intrinsic function `blkdiag` ?

Comment: @Sardar Usama i did put an example of output.

Comment: The output matrix has 12 rows and 16 columns?

Comment: Well, it has 30 rows and 432 columns. that was just an small example.

Comment: How exactly? if you put d matrix at its place, there cannot be 30 r and 432 cols?

Comment: I know, it's OK i just want to have d matrix for first 30 columns and other columns would remain zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`spdiags`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spdiags.html) to create a diagonal `[10 x 108]` sparse matrix then use [`kron`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html) to scale and fill the matrix.

```
d = [ 1 1 0 0; 0 0 1 1; 0 0 0 0]
size_D=[30, 432];
sz = size_D./size(d);
diagonal = spdiags(ones(sz(1),1),0,sz(1),sz(2));
result = kron(diagonal ,d);
```